# XirSys Credentials Validation

Tags: c#, webrtc, turn

I have performed the POST request to XirSys to retrieve my list of servers and credentials per their [Getting Started Guide](http://xirsys.com/files/docs/index.php/Quick_Start_Guide).

Is there a way to confirm that the credentials XirSys provides me work? I am passing them into a third party conferencing solution and it `relay` candidates are not created.

Using a custom TURN server solution, the conferencing works as expected so I'm looking for a way to validate that the user/password I am using for XirSys is functioning.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your initial POST request worked. If it worked, you should have received an alert with a status of 200. That should be all the confirmation you need -- you'll only get 200 if all credentials are correct.

As far as passing them into a third party, what conferencing solution is this? Do you have any code that I can work with to help you?

If it's a super specific use case, please contact us at experts@xirsys.com and we'll fix you up from there.

Comment: I was referring to the POST w/ my `ident` and `secret` that returned back `username` and `credentials`. I then pass that username and credentials into the conference but I'd like to validate my credentials outside of the other third party.

Comment: Like I said, I think you'll have to give me more information to work with. I'd be able to provide a specific answer if I had example code or even a name of the third party conference. [=

Comment: Sure, we are using IceLink from (frozenmountain.com). Their Conference (http://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink2/#class=IceLink.DotNet45.FM.IceLink.Conference) takes a `RelayUsername` and `RelayPassword` which we set to the credentials given back from Xirsys. We tell it to use the server / port provided in our initial Xirsys request (turn1.xirsys.com and 443 respectively). One speculation is maybe the credential value in the json not what we should use as the relay password?

Comment: This problem has been solved. The Frozen Mountain team and the XirSys team worked closely to get both services working together. Expect related documentation to be added soon.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I was passing my email instead of the username.
Passing the username fixed it for me.